# Why in IE8 <script /> won't work with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have a website using ASP.NET MVC, everything was working fine, but I'd like to add some jquery stuff, then I imported the .js in my master page and when I run it my page doesn't work in the Internet Explorer anymore, I only get the background color. In Google Chrome it works nice, so in Firefox. Then I got a look in some pages in the web and I realized that they were using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src"..."></script>
```

and not

```
<script type="text/javascript" src"..." />
```

like I was. I did this change and it work! But how I can explain it, why the short way won't work in IE 8?

Comment: Can you please provide HTML source?

Comment: The question might be, is <script /> valid HTML or is it xHTML/XML?

Comment: Sorry, I did provide but forgot to say it was code, so this page was hiding it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)